# Which way of defining routes is more Rails Way-ish and recommended?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

Let's say all I need for now is just a GET REST service that returns the JSON when I go to this address:

```
http://localhost:3000/population_management/1.json
```

One way is to define it this way:

```
resources :population_management, :only => [:show]
```

And one way is to define it this way:

```
  resources :population_management

  match "population_management/:id" => "population_management#show", :via => :get
```

And I am sure there are other ways too, So what is your recommendation and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the **first** solution is clearer. plus Rails already defines what you've written in solution two (by using `resources` -> [see here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web)) , so let Rails do it's job, only limit these resources to 1 route.